# Java regex confusing

Tags: java, regex

i want parse string like this

```
  0.1142     0.0000     0.0000     0.0004     0.0000     0.0000    2299/2299        MakeRequest   [23]
```

I want get ol doubles from this string. I am using next pattern

```
.+ ([0-9\\.]+) [\\p{Space}]+ ([0-9\\.]+) [\\p{Space}]+ ([0-9\\.]+) [\\p{Space}]+ ([0-9\\.]+) [\\p{Space}]+ ([0-9\\.]+) [\\p{Space}]+ ([0-9\\.]+) [\\p{Space}]+ ([0-9\\/])+ [\\p{Space}] "\\.(MakeRequest) .+
```

And this string is parsed well.
But i cann't parse next string!

```
    20.1600     0.0001     0.0000     0.0053     0.0001     0.0000  383248/383248      MakeRequest   [22]
```

This string are very similar! But first is parsed, second not:-(

**Update**
Easily pattern

```
.+ ([0-9\\.]+) .+ ([0-9\\.]+) .+([0-9\\.]+) .+ ([0-9\\.]+) .+ ([0-9\\.]+) .+ ([0-9\\.]+) .+ ([0-9\\/])+ .+\\.(MakeRequest) .+
```

Don't works too

I'm using

```
java.util.regex.Pattern
```

and

```
java.util.regex.Matcher
```

Comment: Are there supposed to be two `+` symbols between the last two groupings? `[\\p{Space}]+ + "\\.(MakeRequest) .+`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ([0-9\.]+) .+ ([0-9\/])+

Matches SPACE, ONE OR MORE CHARACTERS, SPACE (total of 3 characters)

Second string has only 2 spaces.

> 0.0000  383248/383248

Comment: Between the numbers that is, which is where it fails (didn't check if it fails anywhere else too).

Answer (score 2):

What would be wrong with code like the following:

```
  final Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\d+\\.\\d+").matcher(s); // s is your line
  while (m.find()) System.out.println(Double.parseDouble(m.group()));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is pattern to get all doubles

```
[0-9]*\.[0-9]*
```